# Setup POST HTTP Request to create variable .vnc file

Tags: python, html, django, post, vnc

I have a database with users information and IP's. What I would like to do is to dynamically create, and then open, a *.vnc file with their IP.

In my `views.py` file I have this:

```
def view_list(request):
    template_name = 'reader/list.html'
    cust_list = xport.objects.all()
    #if request.method == 'POST':
        #<a href=link to created *.vnc file>Connect to client</a>
    return render(request, template_name, {'xport': cust_list})
```

The commented out portion is just what I've been playing with and what I currently think I need to do.

My template file is `list.html` and looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load url from future %}


{% block content %}
<h1> Customer List </h1>

<ul>
    {% for c in xport %}
        {% if c.ip %}
            <li>{{ c.firstName }} {{ c.lastName }}</li>
            <form method="POST" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create VNC to {{ c.ip }}" />
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

What I would like to do is to click on the "Create VNC" button and then that create and open the *.vnc file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea:

```
url(r'^file/vnc/$', 'myapp.views.vnc', name='vnc-view'),
```

views.py

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
def vnc(request):
    ip = request.POST.get('ip', None)
    response = HttpResponse(ip, content_type='application/octet-stream')
    # If you don't want the file to be downloaded immediately, then remove next line
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="ip.vnc"'
    return response
```

template

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'vnc-view' %}">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="127.0.0.1" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create VNC to 127.0.0.1" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I was able to use what you sent and make it work.  I just added what you sent me into my view and made the button download the file.  I'm going to explore how to make it download and then open the file now.  Thanks again!